# Previous and Next Button for post on wordpress

Tags: css, post, pagination, wordpress, blogs

I am trying to figure out how I can change the typical pagination links (i.e Pages: 1 2 3) at the bottom of a WordPress post show up as "Previous" and "Next buttons instead.

Just like: http://mediawtf.com/featured-posts/walk-on-water/

Comment: Google for pagination
https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [Pagination](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination).

But, bearing [Joe Kennedy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2856441/joe-kennedy)'s comment in mind, here I go:

Basically, there are two methods that are used to control pagination, and they are `next_posts_link( 'Older posts' )` and `previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' )`. They should be placed where your main loop is. (I'm assuming you know what the main loop is, and also that you webside structure is fairly simple). Should you be using `WP_query`, don't forget to set you `paged` parameter, like so: `$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;`

If you experience problems with broken pagination (i.e., 404s), I suggest you flush your permalink settings (again, assuming you know what I'm talking about, your question didn't give any hints as of your level of knowledge). You can do that by re-saving the rules. In most (simple) cases, that does the trick.

I have seen custom pagination being crafted inside plugins and themes with custom post types, taxonomies and whatnot, but I think that goes beyond the scope of your question.

I suggest you read the codex (first link I posted). It's crystal clear, and has tons of examples. In case you have doubts, try zeroing in on your problem, and perhaps give us some code snippets, so we can help you better.